# Docker & wordpress - Error establishing a database connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I found many resolved topics about my issue but I still do not manage to fix it. It might be another issue or most probably have I not manage to understant what was going wrong. After weeks of tests, I do try to ask publicly for some support.

I'm trying to set up a wordpress on my personal server (Ubuntu 22.04).

Below is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  wp-db:
    container_name: wp-mysql_container
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      TZ: "Europe/Paris"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ZZZZ
      MYSQL_USER: mywpuser
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mywpdb
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: XXXX
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3307
    volumes:
      - ./wp-db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3307:3307
  
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress_container
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - wp-db
    ports:
      - 8082:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: wp_db:3307
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: mywpuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: XXXX
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: mywpdb
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./wordpress_logs:/var/log/apache2

  wp-phpmyadmin:
    container_name: wp-phpmyadmin_container
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    depends_on:
      - wp-db
    links: 
      - wp-db:wp-db
    ports: 
      - 8083:80
    environment:
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 100000000
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  wordpress:
  wordpress_logs:
  wp-db:
  wp-db_data:
```

When I try to reach for the wordpress of the phpmyadmin, I get the error message " Database Error : Error establishing a database connection"

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

I tried to follow those related topics:

- [Wordpress Docker "Error establishing a database connection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60366969/wordpress-docker-error-establishing-a-database-connection)
- [Docker Wordpress: Error establishing a database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69437867/docker-wordpress-error-establishing-a-database-connection)
- [DOCKER and WordPress: Error establishing a database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62435593/docker-and-wordpress-error-establishing-a-database-connection)

Among many others...

EDIT: 2023/10/09
Now my docker-compose is as such and is working:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress_container
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8082:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: wp_db_mysql
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: qqqqqqqqqqq
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: yyyyyyyyyyy
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/htmlqsdgjuytac
  wp_db_mysql:
    container_name: wp_mysql_container
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3307:3307
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: yyyyyyyyyyy
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: bbbbbbbbbb
      MYSQL_USER: qqqqqqqqqqq
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
  wp_phpmyadmin:
    container_name: wp_phpmyadmin_container
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    depends_on:
      - wp_db_mysql
    ports:
      - 8083:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3307
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
volumes:
  wp_data:
  db_data:
```

However, when I try to change the MYSQL_PASSWORD changing all "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa" to "nlkjazjeuzagq". I get again the error message.
I tried:

- docker-compose up -d
- docker-compose down && docker image prune -af followed by docker-compose up -d.

Obviously I can't believe "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa" is the only password acceptable but I do not manage to re-initialiaze it.

Comment: The standard MySQL port number is 3306, not 3307.  Does changing the port number to 3306 everywhere it appears in the file help?  (The first `ports:` number can be different but isn't used in this particular setup.)  If not, is there any more to the error message that might suggest how it's failing to connect?

Comment: Thanks David. 3306 is already used for another service, a LAMP server. I do not know if I should have "ports: 3307:3307" or ports: "3307:3306" tbh. I am a bit reluctant to kill my LAMP (and unsure yet how to) to pass everything to 3306. I do not know how/where to get more details about my error message.

Comment: `ports: ['3307:3306']` will map the non-conflicting host port 3307 to the standard database port 3306 inside the container.  Since each container otherwise has an isolated network environment, it's fine for the container to use the standard port even if you have other similar database containers or a database on the host.

Comment: I kept "MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 3307", changed to "ports: - 3307:3306" and changed "WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: wp_db". Is that the changes you had in mind? I still get the same error message unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in the same journey here, and mine WP just started working. See my code below.

Please note that the infamous message *Error establishing a database connection* may still occur: even though `docker` says "done", if you immediately go to the browser you'll get that message. In my case, I have to wait ~5 seconds and then it accepts connection (before that, the message appears).

Also, I've noticed that people suggest `mysql:5.7` instead, so I would advise you to change that (seems to me that other versions (8) are applied at Oracle enterprise systems).

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9010:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: qqqqqqqqqqq
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: yyyyyyyyyyy
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
  mysql:
    container_name: mysqlWordpress
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: yyyyyyyyyyy
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: bbbbbbbbbb
      MYSQL_USER: qqqqqqqqqqq
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 9012:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3307
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
volumes:
  wp_data:
  db_data:
```

Comment: Many thanks rd1218. I did manage to use your code and it worked. Now I can't figure out how to change the password (see my edit).

Comment: Maybe this is the case for another question instead? In my opinion, the original one seems correctly answered (and should be marked as the answer). Anyway, if you couldn't work with the inicial container, just remove it (`docker rm -f <id>`) and proceed with a new one.

Comment: In fact, the phpmyadmin still refuse to connect to the data base. I do not know if it's an issue of mapping the connection (I doubt that) or a login issue that might be linked to the fact that I can't change the mysql password and user...

Comment: Please remove both `PMA_HOST: mysql` and `PMA_PORT: 3307` and have a try. Let me know then I will check to update the answer. For reference, this is my working command: `docker container run -d --name phpMyAdmin --restart always -e PMA_ARBITRARY=1 -p 9000:80 --link mysql phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest`.

Comment: rd1218, sorry for the late reply, I was travelling. Indeed, removing PMA_PORT was the solution! Congratulation. I still do not manage to change your login parameters though. I believe I should wipe out everything beyond just killing the container but I do not find the correct command

Comment: Shall I try to remove manual the 3 WORDPRESS directories under docker/wordpress directory? seems a bit violent to me but...

Comment: In my case, I've already removed and added again those containers several times. Since this is a learning curve, seems expected to me. Anyway, if you're concerned about loosing your website data, please try `updraft` plugin for a backup (about 5x files generated) and then you can restore them. Please notice: to restore to a fresh WP container, you'll need to login to `phpmyadmin` and erase tables regarding the old WP container related.

Comment: Sorry rd1218, trying to remove the database "yyyyyyyyyyy" without success. I wonder if the drop function is not inhibated to avoid to loose connection. I believed using Docker, once bringing down the container removing the image, all data were removed. If that was the case, I would be able to purge everything and start a fresh docker-compose up. Can't I manually remove completely the mysql & phpmyadmin to reinstall everthing from a clean plate?

Comment: When a container is removed the data stored externally (like the database) is not affected. Please check if you are trying this: login to phpMyAdmin, select "site > yyyyyyyyyyy" in the left panel, select all boxes in the right/main panel (button "mark all" at bottom) and then "remove" at dropdown. Therefore, "yyyyyyyyyyy" remains but empty. The you go a fresh `docker container run`.

Comment: Digging into Portainer that I never really use, I found plenty of different volumes linked to WP and the different tentatives I made. BIngo, of course, removing the containers is not sufficient. The solution has been FINALLY reached with "docker-compose down" then "docker system prune -af" and then "docker volume prune". Thanks so much rd1218 for your help and support!

Comment: Good to know. If you consider my above answer correct, please mark it as "answer". This will help future observers of this subject, and also my own reputation at stackoverflow